# Z-index not working in IE for iframe video

Tags: html, css, iframe

for this page strutmymutt.com/rescuetraining/single/jump-furniture, I set up the popup which is shown when we click anywhere on the page if user is not logged in.

In IE, popup is working fine if I click anywhere on the page, but on the video, pop up is not shown when I click on video area, video starts playing. It is working fine in other browsers. Even I set up the wmode= transparent for iframe video

Answer (score 0):

I checked in IE11 and its working fine. Video won't play and it asked for registration. It seems lower IE version have some problem.

could you please try this and paste between `<head>` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Comment: put this code in head tag, but still the same issue

Comment: I am getting this in console
HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=Edge,chrome=1') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 
485l2xx702?videoFoam=true

Comment: I see this problem in IE8 version

Comment: Try to embeded the wistia video in page by another method. i.e.not using iframe method.